# Is there a way for encrypting AWS EC2 instance PostgreSQL database using AWS KMS or else?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, amazon-kms

I need to find a method for encrypting whole database and encrypt specific columns data in PostgreSQL. Currently I have a PostgreSQL database in an Amazon EC2 instance.

Is there a way for encrypting this database using AWS key management service or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for two different use cases and I'd separate them

> I need to find a method for encrypting whole database

As already answered, AWS can encrypt data in rest by default,  data storage is encrypted under the hood (for RDS or EBS). AWS uses KMS to manage the encryption key for encrypting the underlying storage.

This encryption is transparent, so client having the correct database credentials has access to data.

> and encrypt specific columns data

This needs to be done on application level. You have a few options here. The application can encrypt the data directly or you can use [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.8) library to let the database encrypt the data.

The biggest problem in this case is where to store and how to manage the encryption key. The keys can be managed by KMS or [AWS Secret Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/)

With KMS you can create a data encryption key to encrypt data themselves and KMS to encrypt the "data encryption key". Actually - the secret manager is doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PostgreSQL under Amazon Relational Database Service (**Amazon RDS**), you can automatically encrypt the data at rest.

See: [Encrypting Amazon RDS Resources - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)

However, since you have installed PostgreSQL yourself (regardless of the fact that it is on an Amazon EC2 instance), **you would need to manage the encryption yourself**.

See: [PostgreSQL Documentation: Encryption Options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/encryption-options.html)

Comment: Can we encrypt database table or entry using Amazon Relational Database Service?

Comment: If the database is created under Amazon RDS, you can **encrypt the data at rest**. This will apply to all of the database storage. It is not table-level. Are you wanting to encrypt for general security, or are you wanting to hide certain data from certain users?

Comment: We are storing sensitive health data. When someone take the database somehow, we need to still protect our data as unreadable.